# Complexity of T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n/2 (without master's theorem)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, mergesort

I am looking at the best case running time for merge sort, and have found the following recurrence relation: T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n/2. I am aware of the fact that merge sort is theta(nlogn) in all cases. In attempting to solve this recurrence relation, I use telescoping:

```
T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + n/2
T(n) = 2^2*T(n/4) + n/4 + n/2
T(n) = 2^k*T(1) + (n/2 + n/4 + ... + n/2^k) 
2^k = n -> log_2(n) = k
T(n) = n + n(1/2 + 1/4 + ... + 1/n)
```

I am unsure how to solve the summation in the last part... I'm not even sure if that is correct. My thinking is that there would be log_2(n) total items being added in the summation? I am unsure how to derive that 2T(n/2) + n/2 is theta(nlogn) **without using the master's theorem please**...

Comment: You are not telescoping it correctly. T(n) = 2T(n/2)+n/2 = 2(2T(n/4)+n/4)+n/2 = 4T(n/4) + 2n/4 + n/2. After telescoping you have a sum of (log n) elements, each one being equal to n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, your calculation seems to be wrong.

```
T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + n/2
T(n) = 2*(2*T(n/4) + n/4) + n/2  = 4*T(n/4) + 2*(n/4) + n/2 = 4*T(n/4) + 2*(n/2)
T(n) = 4*(2*T(n/8) + n/8) + 2*(n/2) = 8*T(n/8) + (n/2) + 2*(n/2) = 8*T(n/8) + 3*(n/2)
...
T(n) = 2^k * T(n / 2^k) + k*(n/2),       2^k = n --->  k = log(n)
T(n) = log(n) * T(1) + log(n) * (n/2)
T(n) = logn + n*log(n)/2
```

Therefore time complexity of merge sort = `O(n*log(n))`